The relation between voices in piano pieces

I've been trying to understand how to identify the voices within the harmonic progression they form, after learning counterpoint and SATB harmony.
But when I'm investigating the relation between voices more closely (parallel octaves, fifths, harmony, etc) I see segments where the number of voices keep adding or changing.  As a result, I can't really understand the connection between them.  For example, I don't know where the alto is going because the number of voices has changed.
In the picture below, taken from one of Bach's sonatas, I suppose the voices are distinguished by their stem direction where the soprano is always upward and the bass downward, but am I correct that the number of inner voices may increase or decrease?
If I'm correct, here's a follow up question: does this mean we can have 2 altos when the number voices become 5, for example?  I also see in Haydn pieces that the number of voices can sometimes go from 2 to 5; in that case, what became of the missing alto and tenor voices?  Do they mix with each other?
If it goes down from 5 to 2 voices does that mean we now only have the bass and soprano voices?  See measure 8 cadence resolution where you can see 5 voices. The bottom 2 D forming an octave in the left hand part; are they both just the bass, or is the higher D the tenor?

See https://music.stackexchange.com/q/136222/78419 by the way. Music for polyphonic instruments (like piano) may distinguish "voices" sometimes, but it's not actually choir music.

You should distinguish between contrapuntal style with true voices and actual vocal music and homophonic texture music or non-vocal music. The former will usually have a consistent number of voices, because each part is a distinct, independent line or an actual vocal part. The later is less about multiple, actual lines in counterpoint, and more about vertical chords.
Genres that you can associate with the two might be, for example, fugues, choral music, chamber music like string quartets for real distinct parts/voices.
Genres like solo keyboard music, continuo parts, symphonic writing, etc. can be homophonic (melody with bass and chord filler), where chords have a more vertical origin, rather than contrapuntal lines, and instruments do doubling and add coloring rather than act as independent parts/voices.

True sir -So if most of the choral and counterpoint harmony rules are not used in the genres that you mentioned . What actually should i consider and take care of when writing a for example sonata

@user98606 1) Note, counterpoint is its own stricter-than-usual set of rules (or sets, as you have various "species"). 2) Writing your own "real" pieces often comes in theory classes beyond the first year, or in composition classes. It's important to single out a period and genre that you're trying to emulate, as "rules" (practices) changed.

@user98606 for a sonata the typical texture will be homophonic. But remember, your original question was about the number of voices. It isn't a case of homophonic style doesn't use counterpoint rules, it just doesn't have independent voices. In terms of "rules" homophonic style still adheres to good voice leading with special attention to the outer voices of bass and soprano (or bass and main melody.)

Another thing to keep in mind: in a homophonic piece there very often are passage following a contrapuntal texture for a short time. A common thing is to begin a section, ex. the beginning of a sonata development, with a fugal style entry of voices, or some other kind of imitative texture. After a few such entries the music often segues back to a homophonic texture.

Keyboard pieces, even those in a contrapuntal style, often do not adhere to a strict number of voices.  Voices may appear or disappear without warning.  For example, the left hand of the Aria in Bach's Goldberg variations begins in three voices (to indicate that each note of the arpeggiated figure should be sustained) but has only two voices in the seventh and eighth measures.  The same sort of thing is going on in this sonata.
It is not usually necessary to account for every voice at every point in time, and often it is unhelpful.  When composers do want to be explicit about the disposition of the voices when there are fewer notes than voices, they will use multiple stems on a single note head to indicate doubling, or, as Bach does in the Goldberg aria, use rests to indicate that a voice is inactive.

Just for kicks, I've scored the sonata for SATB, with alto and tenor divisi. Looking at it this was, I think, clarifies where the voices are. Although there are as many as six pitches being sung simultaneously, they still fit neatly into four "voices". This is an interpretation, of course, and others might assign parts differently.


In measure 7, you made g last a half note, and it changes the harmony changes a bit: G6 A7sus A7, vs G6 Asus A7. I would think the quarter note (second version) was intentional.

So my question was the same thing you did  ( it's okay to look at 2 voice as one for example tenor 2 voices in tenor ? ( i want to see the relation between the voices and how they move into each other

The term used to cancel "div." is typically "unis."

I think he made it last a half note to make it look less complicated as the G repeats in a quarter note

@user98606 in the original there is no G on the second beat, nor is there a rest.  You have G and E on the first beat with the E tied to an E on the second beat, and then you have G on the third beat.  I checked the manuscript sources (not in Bach's hand) and they are similar but not identical.  Both of them have only E on the second beat, however (along with the A in the bass).

The number of active voices can change within a piece, just like in a band not all instruments play all the time. It also may happen that a voice enters for a very short time. Think of that musician who sits quietly through the whole concert, just to crash cymbals once, at the end of the piece.
In the example you attached, there indeed seem to be 5 voices in the measure 7. I would say, the rhythm could have been notated a bit more clearly, but it seems obvious to me how it's intended to be played.

True but how is are the notes related together ( their movement) is it even useless to check the intervals and voice leading principles for piano pieces? Should i only focus on the root and the bass part that are more obvious ?

Sorry for the typo - i mean't bass and the soprano

@user98606 maybe it's not entirely useless, but some of the rules written in textbooks seem stricter than what the best composers actually did....
